# 'Well I never' or 'Well, I never'?

Tags: punctuation

Which is correct: 'Well I never' (without a comma) or 'Well, I never"? Dictionaries seem to differ on the subject. Maybe both are accepted?

Comment: Hello, Hannelise. Please show the different results you have found. Then someone will say this is purely a matter of style choice: how do you want the reader to read it out?

Comment: Which one? Are you thinking of the chiefly British exclamation (*Well, I never!*) or of things like *Well, I never do this, but others might*? Personally, I'd use a comma for both, but please [edit] your question and add an example sentence.

Comment: I'm talking about the exclamation one uses to express surprise.

Comment: Two replies suggested that I should consider how I want the reader to 'read out' the exclamation. It's usually pronounced, 'Well. I. Never.' So I guess in that case, the comma is useless. Especially taking into consideration another answer that pointed out that exclamations are 'grammar-free zones'.

Answer (score 1):

Exclamations are essentially grammar-free zones. They may contain anything as long as you separate them from other speech with at least commas. Inside an exclamation, how do you want the reader to read it out?

Answer (score 1):

"Well I never", as an exclamation, is rarely pronounced with a pause after "well".  "Well, I never got the letter", on the other hand, IS generally pronounced with a pause.  In ordinary writing (vs technical stuff) commas are used to clue the reader about when to pause.

Particularly in fiction, whether or not to use a comma in an exclamation such as "Well I never!" is entirely up to the author.

Answer (score 0):

Commas are going out of style, it seems, which is really a pity, since they fulfill an important rôle in sentence structure. So I guess one answer would be that, if you want to give an impression of being modern, you write simple sentences, without commas, whereas, if you want to use your written language as a sharp tool, and express complex ideas in complex sentences, you should use commas. In this specific case, the comma puts the stress on "well", creating a suspension, before "I never...". Kinda...